# Substitute number with 2 digits in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have some input that is an integer stored as a string that may have 1 or 2 digits. I would like to know if it is possible to come up with a regex pattern and substitution string that allows me to add a 0 at the front of any input that has only one digit.

ie. I'd like to find pattern and subst such that:

```
Regex.Replace("1",pattern,subst); // returns "01"
Regex.Replace("31",pattern,subst); // returns "31"
```

**Edit: the question is specific to C# regex. Please do not answer to provide alternative methods**

Comment: why don't you use string.Replace function is there a reason why you don't or can't use that..?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(num, r"\b(\d)\b", "0$1");`

Comment: @MethodMan: yes, I only have access to some configuration, I can't change the code

Comment: @anubhava: that will always append a 0 at the front, no? ie, if num is 31, that will return 031, right?

Comment: No it won't make it `031` because of `\b` (word boundary) on both sides.

Comment: @anubhava: huh, that works, but I have no idea why... Can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex you can use word boundaries around a single digit:

```
string num = "5";
Regex.Replace(num, @"\b\d\b", "0$&");
//=> 05

num = "31";
Regex.Replace(num, @"\b\d\b", "0$&");
//=> 31
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/jExlKV)

Regex `\b\d\b` will match a single digit with word boundaries on either side to ensure we're only matching a single digit.

[More Infor about Word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

---

In case digit can appear in the middle of the word then you can use lookarounds regex like this:

```
num = Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(num, @"(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)", "0$&"));
```

Comment: Note that a word boundary won't let you match a chunk of digits in the middle of a word. Also, there is no sense wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group, you can reference the match value with `$&` from the replacement pattern and use a `Regex.Replace(num, @"\b\d\b", "0$&");`, it will do the same.

Comment: OP didn't mention if digits can appear in the middle of the word. If that is the case then we'll need to use lookarounds. Indeed a good suggestion of using `$&` (edited with thanks)